# Copy formatted (cell color/merged cells) data from one excel to another changes color - win32/python

Tags: excel

Trying to copy some data formatted - has cell color as well as merged cells from one excel to another using win32. It changes from purple to a weird brown in this case.

```
xlPasteFormats= -4122
source.Worksheets('Summary').Range("I%d:P%d" %(start,end)).Copy()
xlSheet.Range('B1:I2').PasteSpecial(-4163)     #Pastes data
xlSheet.Range('B1:I2').PasteSpecial(xlPasteFormats)     #Pastes the format
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely due to a difference in the theme colours of the workbooks (assuming source and target sheets are in different workbooks). A solution would be to change the theme colours of the target workbook to match the source workbook. This could be done manually or in the code.

Comment: Yes - they are different work books. Makes sense. Thank you!